# Porcentagem variavel em c

Tags: c

Tenho um problema com um código simples, quero saber como faço para calcular a porcentagem de um valor.

EX: 1500 + 15% (nesse caso eu sei que é valor = valor*0.15)

Porém o valor da porcentagem deve ser uma variavel informada pelo usuario.
Até o momento tenho o seguinte código mas nao creio que ira ajudar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Escreva um programa que leia: o valor de uma aplicação, o
//percentual de rendimento mensal obtido por esta aplicação e o
//período do investimento; e retorne o valor da aplicação ao final do
//período de investimento.

int main (){

    float aplicacao = 0;
    float rendimento = 0;
    float ff = 0;
    int periodo = 0;
    int cont = 0;

    while (cont < periodo){
        ff = aplicacao + rendimento
        cont ++
    }

}
```

Comment: Não seria, 15/100 ?

Comment: @Sveen você quis dizer `15.0/100`, não é mesmo? Em C, se não tiver motivo para fazer divisão de pontos flutuantes, essa divisão não será feita. Por isso é importante garantir que o numerador ou o denominador seja um número de ponto flutuante

Comment: Como será informada essa porcentagem? Será digitado `15` para representar `15%`? Ou será digitado `15.0`? Ou mesmo `0.15`? E aceita parte menor do que `1%`? Por exemplo, faz sentido o usuário entrar com algum valor que represente `15.3%`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Uma solução para isso seria receber um numero inteiro e depois dividi-lo por 100 assim como no code abaixo:

```
  int Num;
  float percen;
  cout << "Lendo a porcentagem...: ";
  cin >> Num;
  percen = Num/100;
```

Você pode saber mais sobre os métodos *cin* e *cout* no link: https://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/PRGSWB/Streams/streams.html

Comment: Sua resposta tem diversos erros. O primeiro é que você respondeu uma dúvida C com coisas do C++ sem dar o devido alerta. Sim, isso é algo importante a ser feito. E C e C++ não são a mesma linguagem. A segunda coisa é que você está realizando divisão inteira de qualquer sorte, não pegando a parte fracionada decorrente da divisão. Então se a pessoa entrar com 99, sua variável `percen` carregará consigo o valor `0.0`, não `0.99`.

Answer (score -2):

Primeiro você precisa do valor em float, ou seja, divida o valor da porcentagem por 100. Toma cuidado com as conversões ( `int result = desc / 100` resultaria em 0, pois as casas decimais seriam truncadas ao converter de float pra int).
Com isso, é só fazer a multiplicação.